# Laravel Mutator Queries every time it's called

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, accessor

I have an document Model which contains VAT id field from another table. when i invoke the value column of the vat model with a mutator it's queried every time a model class is called, is there an alternative way of prefetching the value?

```
public function getVatValueAttribute($value)
{
    $vat = Vat::find($this->vat);
    return $vat->value;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should set up vat relationship like so:

```
public function vatRel()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(Vat::class, 'vat');
}
```

and now you can implement this method like this:

```
public function getVatValueAttribute($value)
{
    return $this->vatRel->value;
}
```

Comment: In the vat table there is an id, name, value and i already have a relationship mapped to the id, as you can see i call the $this->vat property where the id is stored

Comment: Nevermind, long day.. this answer lead me to solving it, bad thing is i have to use with on the initial query all the time. Thanks